# Delete Function Not Working In Angular Js

Tags: angularjs

I am not able to get alert for delete function even if i had done right procedure so please help me for the same.Thanks in advance for solving my problem
I am not able to get alert for delete function even if i had done right procedure so please help me for the same.Thanks in advance for solving my problem

```
<html ng-app="crudApp">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Angular js</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form name="addForm"  ng-submit="Add" ng-controller="employeecontroller">
            First Name: <input type="text" ng-model="firstname"><br/><br/>
           Last Name: <input type="text" ng-model="lastname"><br/><br/>
            <input type="submit" name="btnInsert" value="Insert" ng-click='insertData()'/>
        </form>

        <div ng-controller="DbController">
            <table border="1">
                <tr>
                    <th>Firstname</th>
                    <th>Lastname</th>
                </tr> 
                <tr ng-repeat="detail in details">
                    <td>{{detail.firstname}}</td>
                    <td>{{detail.lastname}}</td>
                    <td><input type="button" value="Delete"  ng-click="deleteInfo()"/></td>
                </tr>
            </table>

        </div>
        <script>

            function employeecontroller($scope, $http) {
                $scope.insertData = function () {
                    $http.post("insert.php", {
                        'firstname': $scope.firstname,
                        'lastname': $scope.lastname,
                    }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                        console.log("Data Inserted Successfully");
                    });
                }
            }

            var crudApp = angular.module('crudApp', []);
            crudApp.controller("DbController", ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
                    // Sending request to EmpDetails.php files
                    getInfo();
                    function getInfo() {
                        $http.post('select.php').success(function (data) {
                            // Stored the returned data into scope

                            $scope.details = data;

                            console.log(data);
                        });
                    }
                }]);

            function DbController($scope,$http) {

                $scope.deleteInfo = function () {
                    alert("hello");

                }
            }

        </script>

    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Did you managed to work with the `employeecontroller`? it looks as if it's not registered to your app. no errors?

Comment: No need to repeat yourself...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each controller should be registered as part of your Angular app. You have registered `DbController` but then created a separate function called `DbController` that Angular is unaware of. Try moving your delete function to the registered controller. Like this:

```
 crudApp.controller("DbController", ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
                    // Sending request to EmpDetails.php files
                    getInfo();
                    function getInfo() {
                        $http.post('select.php').success(function (data) {
                            // Stored the returned data into scope

                            $scope.details = data;

                            console.log(data);
                        });
                    }

                   $scope.deleteInfo = function () {
                    alert("hello");
                    }
                 }
```